# Shell script to find all types of files in a directory with their count

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, perl

I want to write a `shell script` or `alias` to find the number of different types of files in a directory. For example, sample output of script should be:

```
*.h      20
*.c      40
*.cpp    10
Makefile 3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sh -c 'echo ${0##*.}' {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

The `echo ${0##*.}` gives you the extension of the file. We pipe the output to `sort` and then count the unique lines with `uniq`.

Some additions:

- Since the output of `uniq` is not sorted according to the number of occurrences, you'll have to pipe again into a numeric sort (`-nr`) if you want it sorted.
- If you want to search your current directory only, add `-maxdepth 1` to your `find` command.
- Pipe into `awk '{print $2, $1}'` to show the count after the extensions.

Comment: Nice answer. This will not include files without extensions. Is there a simple way to find that?

Comment: The `-name '*.*'` option restricts `find` to files with extensions only. If you leave this out, you'll end up with a count of 1 for every file though, so this might not be ideal.

Comment: You could add a branch in the sh to check if it has an extension, if so print extension, if not print full filename; and find *

Comment: @ClaytonStanley Since the extra `sh` process takes a little more execution time, filtering the results with `find` will be a little faster, I guess.